# How to run more SQL updates in one SQL command?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL commands, which I would like to run in one command. But if I remove the semicolon from between them, then it doesn't works anymore;

```
UPDATE runners SET money=20000
WHERE rrank >= 3;
UPDATE runners SET money=25000
WHERE nev = 'Master';
```

Comment: Can both conditions be true for the same row? If so, which value should be applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial (however generalized) solution (if `runners` is not *that big table*)

```
update runners 
   set money = case
                 when rrank >= 3 then
                   20000
                 when nev = 'Master' then
                   25000
                 -- any number of when here
                 -- if no when applied, do nothing 
                 else
                   money
               end
```

Answer (score 5):

Combine the logic into a single update:

```
UPDATE runners
     SET money = (case when nev = 'Master' then 25000
                       else 20000
                  end)
     WHERE rrank >= 3 or nev = 'Master';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case`

```
UPDATE runners 
SET money = case when rrank >= 3 
                 then 20000
                 when nev = 'Master'
                 then 25000
            end
WHERE rrank >= 3 
or nev = 'Master'
```